# What does "&" (Ampersand) means in Chinese language?

Tags: translation, meaning, etymology, learning

While visiting Dr. Sun Yat-sun Classical Chinese Garden in Vancouver, B.C. I noticed the sign "&" (Ampersand) is posted everywhere. The tour guide said that "&" means money in Chinese, it is the most important sign in Chinese language. I never heard about that before, is it true?

Comment: Can you provide a photo? I can't think out any meaning of & in Chinese except its western usage "and".

Comment: Nor have I ever heard about it. '&' is even not a chinese literal. The same suggestion as above, a photo could be provided and we'll see if it might be some sign else.

Comment: They are wrong, "&" means nothing in Chinese.

Comment: Thanks for your question. We are unsure what you are asking without a picture. Unclear questions result in unclear answers. If you could provide more info and then use "flag" to get moderators to reopen the question once you have edited your question.

Answer (score 4):

maybe you want to check this: http://vancouverchinesegarden.com/calendar/iain-baxter/

Comment: I think this must be the explanation. It's part of an artist's self-chosen "name" (Iain Baxter&) who has an exhibit at the garden in question. His works of art all seem to have an ampersand in them.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you could be looking at a highly calligraphic "钱", or qián, which means "money". I could see those swirly lines bleeding together and looking like an "&".

I'm stumped for any other ideas!

Answer (score -1):

Traditional Chinese money is "￥". （Your PC's input mode to Chinese, and then press "Shift" and then input "4"）。